# R - plotly - How do I change the name/title of the color name above the color legend?

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

In plotly in R, I've added two traces, each with the `color` value set to a variable. It works, but then legend displays the true variable name, and given I've added `color` to two traces it shows it twice in this case. How can I change this name so I see "Year" (title-case) only once? I've tried every `add_trace`/`add_markers` and `layout` setting (mostly looking at `yaxis`) that I can think of, to no effect.

Note that it's not the legend of the traces themselves, which is separate, below, and matches the `name` value given to each marker. It seems there's some other kind of parameter, I'm assuming nested in the trace somewhere, that sets the name of the color?

[image]

```
  add_markers(
    name = "All",
    marker = list(
      size = 10,
      opacity = 0.7
    ),
    data = gsod_accum,
    frame = ~frame,
    color = ~year,
    x = ~mo_num,
    y = ~avg_temp
  ) %>%
  add_trace(
    name = "Selected",
    ids = ~mo_num,
    data = gsod_filt,
    color = ~year,
    frame = ~year,
    marker = list(
      symbol = "diamond",
      # color = ~avg_temp,
      size = 30,
      opacity = 0.5
      ),
    x = ~mo_num,
    y = ~avg_temp
```

Comment: I tried adding the following but it creates a weird huge colorbar first frame, then goes away and problem still exactly the same. I tried this in both the `add_markers` block (did weird stuff) and `add_trace` block (did nothing).
```
    marker = list(
      colorbar = list(title = "Year"),
```

Comment: (per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66900541/plotly-r-setting-the-title-of-a-continuous-color-legend?rq=2)

Comment: You can call the function `colorbar`. For example `%>% colorbar(title = "Not YEAR!")` If this does not work, you'll have to make your question reproducible. If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()` and any libraries you are using. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: Thank you @Kat. I'll give it a try. Sorry was a mad rush and not easy to make it reproducible, but will see how I go. Was hoping it was something simple and obvious. Will keep you posted!

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001518/add-title-to-the-plotly-legend/) you can find a related question.